# Is SER aluminum cable okay for INTERIOR run to sub-panel?

Tags: garage, subpanel, cables, service

I have a short run between a main panel and an attached garage with a sub panel. A SER rated aluminum cable is routed along rafters and between studs, not exposed to wet or sun, and not enclosed in any conduit. I think I'm okay with ampacity, including allowance for line drop and load.  Part of the run may soon end up under blown loose insulation.

**Is SER cable (e.g. 4-4-4-2 Al SER) a good way to go, and is it permitted under current NEC?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's fine, the aluminum wire won't suffer any damage that copper wouldn't.   It also won't suffer from dissimilar metal trouble on the panel lugs and breaker, since those lugs are made of aluminum.

Runors about aluminum's unfitness applied to small branch circuit conductors; feeders have always been reliable.

Comment: What is the description of a subpanel that would accept 6-6-6-6 aluminum (50 A 2-pole breaker in main panel), contain two to four single pole breakers for two 120 V circuits and send 6-6-6-6 copper (6 feet away) to a NEMA 14-50. Could the copper just be connected through lugs or would there have to be a 2-pole breaker (40 A?) in the subpanel?

Comment: @Jim I'd have questions about the Load Calculation for a panel like that.  2-2-2-4 is also cheap :) But "any subpanel" should suffice; NEMA 3R rating needed if outside.

Comment: With all four coil burners removed the 240 V circuit from the subpanel to the NEMA 14-50R would never exceed 25 A and would probably be less than 20 A. But the instructions to the stove say 40 A minimum. If I would put in a 2-pole 30 A breaker, I am sure this would be way more than the oven would ever draw. Would that improve the load calculation?  We actually use the oven infrequently.

Comment: @Jim you would need to create new nameplate data for your permanently modified range, and then plug that into a NEC 220.82 Load Calculation.

Comment: My range is not "permanently modified". I have simply unplugged and removed all four of  the coil heating elements. I could reinsert one or more of them at any time and restore the range to its original functionality. My stove is habitually, temporarily modified, not "permanently modified".

Comment: @Jim I don't think code will let you downsize the circuit, then.  You know how it feels about pinky promises like "I promise to only charge my car at night" or "I promise to shut off the main before starting the generator" etc.

Comment: The plaque on the stove states 13.3 kW. at 120 V/ 240 V. There are four surface burners: two large 2350 W and two small 1325 W giving 7.35 kW for the surface units. The oven has a baking element 2500 W and a broiling element 3400 W. All of which adds up to 13.25 kW.  But our two 1.8 kW induction burners total 3.6 kW. Does the code "worry" that if the 50 A 240 V circuit would be tapped for two 120 V 20 A circuits and the four original resistance elements were to be put back in the stove top, and the two 120 V 20 AA circuits would be loaded, then this'd be over the rating of the 50 A circuit?

Comment: @Jim that number bounces through a calculation at NEC 220.55 to account for load diversity and the fact that heating elements cycle on/off.